# TYPO3 behind proxy generates absolute links with http instead of https

Tags: ssl, https, typo3, reverse-proxy

I’m currently stuck with an issue regarding TYPO3 behind a proxy and the proxy connecting the webserver to the client using ssl. I’ve configured the reverse proxy and tried al, three options for `reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue` (none, first, last) and set `reverseProxySSL` to `*` and the system now generates all typolinks with an absolut path, including http:// instead of just returning the relative path, as I’d have expected. Any thoughts on how to force *not* adding the scheme to typolinks?

TYPO3_CONF_VARS:

```
[SYS][reverseProxyIP] = xx.yy.zz.aa
[SYS][reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue] = 'last'
[SYS][reverseProxySSL] = *
```

I've defined a baseUrl like this, too:

```
config.baseUrl = /
```

I can post additional configuration information if needed.

Regards
Tizian

Comment: do you have config.absRefPrefix set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `config.absRefPrefix = /` and left `config.baseUrl` empty.

Comment: This solved the problem on one instance. On the other instance, I had to set an Apache mod_proxy option `ProxyPreserveHost` since TYPO3 wasn't able to determine the http_host properly, even if giving it the correct reverse proxy ip address.